# calling method in nested module included in class

Tags: ruby, module

I have the following configuration:

```
module A
  module B
    def foo
      puts "foo"
    end
  end
end

class C
  include A
end

c = C.new
c.foo
NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for #<C:0x8765284>
```

How do I achieve the above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Module B is "defined" inside of A, it is not "included" in A. This is why you don't get access to the #foo instance method when you include the A module in C. You could do the following:

```
class C
  include A::B
end

C.new.foo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `included` callback to have `B` include when `A` is included.

```
module A
 def A.included(klass)
  klass.include B
 end

 module B
  def foo
   puts "foo"
  end
 end
end

class C
 include A
end
```

and the following would work

```
c = C.new
c.foo
```